# Botão desabilitado modificado usando firebug

Tags: javascript, html

Imaginem que em um HTML eu tenho um botão desabilitado. Posso muito bem usar o Firebug para habilitar esse botão e assim fazer a submissão.

A questão é: tem alguma maneira de eu desabilitar esse botão e não permitir essa submissão nem mesmo quando eu modifico a propriedade `disabled` do botão no Firebug?

Eu tenho que sempre fazer um tratamento no servidor, pensando que essa possibilidade pode acontecer?

Comment: porque você não remove o botão do html?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro mesmo escondendo o botão o usuário mal intencionado pode submeter o formulário por JS.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi não falei de esconder e sim remover mesmo, pq ele ta enviando um HTML ao cliente com o botão?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro esconder ou remover o botão é o menor dos problemas, porque escondido ou removido da tela o formulário pode ser enviado via JS por um usuário mal intencionado.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi mas se for removido como o cara sabe que tem q enviar algo?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro pra ter alguma interação maliciosa somente submetendo o formulário para o servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A questão de **segurança** contra ações e manipulação de dados acidentais ou maliciosas em aplicações web vai muito além de simplesmente inibir botões ou campos.

A primeira referência que eu li sobre segurança quando estava aprendendo a programar foi no [Manual do PHP](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.variables.php). É uma boa referência mesmo para quem desenvolve em outras linguagens. Considere o seguinte trecho do manual:

> **Você sempre deve examinar cuidadosamente seu código para se assegurar
>   que quaisquer variáveis sendo enviadas do navegador web estão sendo
>   checadas de maneira correta**, e faz a si mesmo as seguintes perguntas:
>
> - Seu script só afetará os arquivos desejados?
> - Dados incomuns ou indesejados podem ser utilizados?
> - Esse script pode ser usado de maneiras não intencionadas?
> - Ele pode ser usado en conjunto com outros scripts de maneira negativa?
> - As transações serão registradas adequadamente?

Enfim, **todos os dados recebidos no seu script de fontes externas devem ser considerados potencialmente perigosos e adequadamente validados**.

Isso inclui:

- Cabeçalhos (*headers*)
- Variáveis de URL (parâmetros `GET`)
- Conteúdo de formulário (parâmetros `POST`)
- Conteúdo de Ajax (Json, XML)
- Cookies
- Arquivos (*uploads*)
- Imagens, HTML e outros recursos consumidos de URLs externas.

Além da validação de valores, algo que os desenvolvedores frequentemente esquece é verificar de o usuário é quem diz ser (**autenticação**) e pode executar uma determinada ação (**autorização**).

É em decorrência disso que em muitos sistemas é possível usurpar o direito de administrador habilitando botões via *firebug*, ferramenta do desenvolvedor ou tendo conhecimento de uma URL "secreta"!

Answer (score 4):

## Resposta:

Você não pode fazer nada em questão de HTML, contra alguém que abra o firebug e saia modificando as coisas.

## Explicação:

Você só pode ter segurança se você validar no Servidor, pois qualquer método que você utilizar com [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) ou [html](/questions/tagged/html) o mesmo método o "cara com o firebug" também pode fazer. Ou seja, não tem jeito, tem que validar no Servidor, aí sim você terá segurança.

**Porém, você deve fazer a validação no cliente(com javascript) e também no Servidor, é sempre mais seguro desta forma.**

Dica: você pode usar de "artimanhas" para dificultar no lado do cliente, por exemplo:

Digamos que todo campo tenha um certo "atributo requerido para submissão" que seria algo inventado por você. Aí você validaria cada campo com seu respectivo "atributo requerido para submissão" por exemplo:

```
<input type=text data-required="HFG2#4DF@">
```

Este seria um campo válido por ter o tal `data-required`, ai teriamos um campo desabilitado:

```
<input type=text disabled>
```

Mesmo que o usuário de firebug vá até ele e remova o atributo disabled, não irá funcionar pois, você checa se todos os campos tem este data-required usando:

```
if ($(seuInput).attr('data-required') == "HFG2#4DF@")
//submete o formulário
else
//não submete o formulário.
```

Aí seria impossivel enviar o tal campo se não colocar o atributo inventado.

Nota: este `HFG2#4DF@` é só um exemplo que você pode dificultar a vida de alguém fazendo ele ter que vasculhar e entender os seus códigos javascript para poder submeter este campo.

Também há diversos meios de fazer estas coisas, como por exemplo você pode colocar um ID diferente para cada campo e usar um `data-required` diferente para cada um que poderia ser o o Código MD5 do ID de cada um, ou então um Base64 do ID de cada um.

Mas claro, isso afetará um pouco a performance e só é usado se você realmente quer dificultar a submissão do formulário a este ponto, não é que seja recomendado fazer isto, é apenas opcional.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, o ideal é que a validação seja feita tanto em client-side como em server-side. Você pode tentar bloquear que o botão seja habilitado por meio de um código javascript, mas pelo próprio Firebug é possível desabilitar a execução do javascript.

Na verdade, idealmente toda validação deve acontecer client-side e, principalmente, server-side.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, você tem sempre que fazer o tratamento no servidor.

Na verdade, não é nem necessário um *browser* (navegador) para fazer requisições HTTP potencialmente hostis ao seu servidor. Um programador malicioso (*hacker*) pode usar ferramentas de programação para dialogar diretamente com o seu servidor usando HTTP ou outros protocolos.

Não tem, mas nem que tivesse uma maneira de desabilitar o botão e não permitir essa submissão nem mesmo quando modificando a propriedade `disabled` do botão no Firebug... ainda assim a vulnerabilidade continuaria existindo. Entende?